# Call a jsp on tomcat server behind a internal alb from html page on apache http in same az on front end of internal alb

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, curl

Overview of vpc.
4 tiers -
public-sn with bastion connected to IGW of course.
internet-facing alb - the target is web-sn
web-sn private with ec2 Linux with apache HTTP installed
internal alb - input from web-sn - outbound all port 80 to internal alb
app-sn - 1 Linux ec2 running tomcat 9 - using iptables to redirect all port 80 traffic from internal-alb to port 8080 for tomcat. easy and works great.
DB-sn - private - 1 MySQL RDS instance. -NOT PART OF THIS DISCUSSION OR PROBLEM.

Situation:
I built a simple test JSP app on tomcat. Just an HTML form input for user and pass and a submit button. JSP form to echo back the input box data. easy, works great locally on the tomcat server.

Action:
I moved the index.html form to the apache HTTP server in web-sn and changed the form action to the URL using DNS of the internal alb. I used the curl command to test at the CLI of the web server and worked great. Of course, it only returns the .jsp contents.
Problem:
When I access the webpage from my local chrome browser page comes up fine. when I click the submit button times out after a minute "This site can't be reached" ERR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT. of course, it spits out the URL I used in the form action.
code:
curl internal-App-ALB-Internal-xxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/LoginCheck.jsp
works great no matter what the page JSP or HTML.

IT FAILS
Index.html on web server ********************

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Login Page</h1>
<center>
    <h2>Signup Details</h2>
    <form action="http://internal-App-ALB-Internal-xxxxxxxxxx.us-west- 
 1.elb.amazonaws.com/LoginCheck.jsp" method="post">
    <br/>Username:<input type="text" name="username">
    <br/>Password:<input type="password" name="password">
    <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

END of html code ***************

Understanding:
From what I understand form action command is server-side.
curl command is using HTTP port 80
why does curl work at CLI of web server just fine and form action from HTML page on the same web server fail?

My security group settings must be good because the curl command works great. I have done other tests as well. I ssh tunnel to alb as well as all other subnets and all works great. I access tomcat manager through the internal app lb and works fine.

Please help with my lack of knowledge.
Thank you.

Comment: As you probably aware this is all inside of a AWS VPC I created. Sorry not directly indicated in article.

Comment: Submitting the form sends a `POST` request from your browser to the address specified by `action`. Therefore `action` must be a publicly accessible URL.

Comment: Ok...Thank you for your reply. Your statement of public URL is not true. This is a common configuration in AWS and other cloud providers where you web servers are in there own private subnet front ended by a internet facing load balancer. The web back end is facing the application servers front ended by an internal application load balancer. As you should know application load balancers only pass port 80 and 443 traffic. I then use ipdatbles redirect for all port 80 traffic to 8080. Please understand the technology and read my words to get the full picture.  I appreciate it.

Comment: The web servers can be in a private network, but in `action` you must specify a hostname that resolves to your external load balancer (you don't type `http://internal-App-ALB-Internal-xxxxxxxxxx.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com` in your browser, do you?). You can also use a relative URL `action="/LoginCheck.jsp"`.

Comment: This infrastructure is a private vpc on aws.All resources that are in private subnets inside the same vpc / CIDR can talk to each other privately. This is how it's done.
The web subnet is private. It however is frontended by internet facing alb.The application subnet is private. The web servers (apache http) connect to the application servers through an internal application load balancer. These only have private dns. The application servers have apache tomcat 9 installed.  -cont-

Comment: -cont- This is your logic layer. The web layer uses apache http to serv general static content. It also reached back to the application layer to tomcat to run java, jsp etc and retrieve data from the database layer. This is how it's done in distributed multi-tier designs.

Comment: This design is a secure design. The only public subnet has bastion hosts (jump servers and nat gateways) Everything else is secure in private subnets. This is a multi-tier, multi AZ design. Used millions of times. thank you for your replies. I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not a , java, J2EE , jsp code guy. I architect enterprise infrastructure as my day job...lol. I just thought I would write some code to use for these designs so I could test them before release to the other teams.

Comment: Here is a link, one of thousands showing this design. I hope this helps. I sure can use help in the code area...lol  https://medium.com/the-andela-way/designing-a-three-tier-architecture-in-aws-e5c24671f124

Comment: BTW - All internal private resources in your private vpc will resolve to each other unless you control the dataflow using security groups (firewalls). just fyi

Comment: From the application's perspective it doesn't really matter how long the daisy chain of forwarding hosts (reverse proxies, DNATs, load balancers, etc.) is: your browser asks `a.example.com` for `/index.html` and the request is transmitted through a long chain to `z.example.com` which returns the HTML page. When your browser submits the form, it must send the data to `a.example.com` again. Of course if you log on a machine in the middle of the daisy chain, `curl http://m.example.com/...` will also work, but it won't work on your local machine.

Comment: Your right, I agree. I guess I have not well explaining myself. Sorry. The web page as shown in my starting of this thread above is simple. Just 2 txt boxes and a submit btn. This can all be reached from the internet. The problem starts when I click the submit btn.It supposed to reach back to the application server (tomcat) to a jsp and just echo back the txt bx info. When I ssh tunnel into the app server and hit port 
-cont-

Comment: -cont-
8080 the whole thing works great. So I took the index.html page from there and put it on the web server (apache httpd) and changed the form action to the url (private ip) of the internal alb in front of the tomcat server. Try again and just fails. Times out "this site can't be reached". SO I though well I will take the internal alb out of the design and just open up the security groups for port 80 and 8080 between the 2 ec2

Comment: -cont-
boxes and try it again. nope fails same way. Yet I can use the curl command on the web server and it works right away. Of course the curl cmd only returns the page contents but it works. So I beleive it must be some kind of IAM role issue because it should work. Apache runs under tomcat user and group but using curl it's root. so I'm thinking it's a permission issue between ec2 instances or something in the call of a jsp page to a backend application server like request.getContextPath(), but that does not return a value either. Thoughts?

Comment: I believe I understand where the problem comes from: did you configure Apache as a reverse proxy for Tomcat? You can do it with [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html). Apache should receive all web requests and decide whether to serve them directly or forward them to Tomcat.

Comment: I have not. Hmmm. All I did was set up iptables on the tomcat server and any port 80 requests coming in redirect to pot=rt 8080. But since I took down the internal load balancer for now and gone direct between the subnets and opened up the security groups I thought I was golden. Thank you thank you. I will try it as soon as I figure that out...lol

Comment: So the apache server will handle all static related things and then as a mod proxy it will send the request to my jsp pages on the backend tomcat server in the app layer? Is this how this will work?

Comment: Basically yes: when you request a static resource Apache will retrieve it from its own filesystem, when you request a JSP page, Apache will retrieve it from Tomcat (probably through the internal load balancer). Apache can directly contact the load balancer, while your browser can not.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and the comments below it becomes clear that you should configure a reverse proxy on your Apache server. Let's say the Apache server has a domain name `apache.example.com` which resolves to a public IP (in reality this is the IP of your bastion host, but through a series of load balancers/firewalls/DNATs/etc., which are not relevant to this explanation, port 80 of `apache.example.com` is forwarded to port 80 of your Apache virtual machine). For simplicity's sake let us also assume that Tomcat has a private address `tomcat.example.com` reachable from the Apache host.

Since `tomcat.example.com` is a private address, you can not use it directly in your HTML, you need to configure Apache to forward all requests for `*.jsp` pages to Tomcat. This can be done with:

```xml
<VirtualHost>
  ...
  <!--
    This will tell Tomcat to use `apache.example.com` in the URLs
    it generates, instead of `tomcat.example.com:8080`
  -->
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  <LocationMatch "\.jsp$">
    ProxyPass "/" "http://tomcat.example.com:8080/"
  </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

You need also to load the `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` modules.

If you add more Tomcat servers, you can also use Apache as a load balancer:

```xml
<VirtualHost>
  ...
  <!--
    This will tell Tomcat to use `apache.example.com` in the URLs
    it generates, instead of `tomcat.example.com:8080`
  -->
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  <Proxy balancer://tomcat-cluster>
    BalancerMember "http://tomcat1.example.com:8080"
    BalancerMember "http://tomcat2.example.com:8080"
    BalancerMember "http://tomcat3.example.com:8080"
  </Proxy>
  <LocationMatch "\.jsp$">
    ProxyPass "/" "balancer://tomcat-cluster/" stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=On
  </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

(you also need to enable the `mod_proxy_balancer` module)

The [`nofailover`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) parameter must be `On`, unless you configure a [Tomcat cluster](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) with session replication.